# jenkins email-ext not sending to developers

Tags: git, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

This issue seems to be specific to the git pull request build jobs. The Pull Request build job builds the following

```
    git repository location  
    origin  
    +refs/pull-requests/*:refs/remotes/origin/pull-requests/*  
    origin/pull-requests/*/from


    editable email setup  
    trigger: failure-any  
    send to developers
```

build output:
Email was triggered for: Failure - Any
Sending email for trigger: Failure - Any
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.

this editable email setup works with no issues when building specific git branches.

```
Jenkins version=1.580.3  
git client=1.16.1  
git plugin=2.3.5  
email ext plugin=2.39
```

thoughts?